# json php вывести по датам

Tags: php, mysql, json

есть json массив, как мне вывести значения в таком порядке:

```
Datam
 - namel
 - namel
 - namel
Datam
 - namel
 - namel

[
{"MIGX_id":"1","datam":"2018-03-15 01:30:00","logo":"img/aside-soccer.png","namel":"АНГЛИЯ - ЧЕМПИОН-ЛИГА","command":"Вулверхэмптон - Куинз Парк Рейнджерс","koef":"1.97"},
{"MIGX_id":"2","datam":"2018-03-29 01:30:00","logo":"img/aside-soccer.png","namel":"АНГЛИЯ - ЧЕМПИОН-ЛИГА","command":"Вулверхэмптон - Куинз Парк Рейнджерс","koef":"1.97"}
]
```

пока у меня так, но что-то туплю

```
$array = json_decode($parent_name['vl'], true);
foreach ($array as $elem){
                if ($elem['datam'] >= $databegin && $elem['datam'] <= $dataend && $elem['koef'] >=1.7 && $elem['koef'] <= 2.3){
                echo '<tr>
                    <td class="flag" style="background-image: url('.$elem['logo'].');">
                    </td>
                    <td class="title">
                        <small>'.$elem['namel'].'</small>
                            <span class="time">'.date("h-i", strtotime($elem['datam'])).'</span>
                            <span class="fore">  Прогноз на матч  <ins>'.$elem['command'].'</ins></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="coeff main-coeff">
                        <a href="">
                            '.$elem['koef'].'
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
                $flag = $flag + 1;
                break;
                }
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чем проблема то? Что не получается?

Comment: я что-то не понял суть вопроса.

Comment: просто есть например 5 записей с одинаковыми датами, мне нужно их сгруппировать по датам и вывести 1 дата и например 5 namel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сгруппировать вы можете вот таким образом

```
   $array = json_decode($parent_name['vl'], true);

    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $key = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($element['datam'])));
        $result[$key][] = $element;
    }

    ksort($result);

  foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
     echo  "<ul>".$value[0]['datam'];
      foreach ($value as $item) {
            echo  "<li>-- ".$item['namel']."</li>";
      }
     echo "</ul>";
  }
```

Comment: сделал как вы показали, выводит вот так, не группируя, картинка в вопросе

Comment: Попробуйте заменить вот эту строку
$result[strtotime($element['datam'])][] = $element;
на
$result[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($element['datam']))][] = $element;

Comment: спасибо сработало